# mysql Как заменить последнее вхождение в строке?

Tags: mysql

Мой SQL удаляет все вхождения.
Как удалить только последний `<br>` ?

```
SELECT REPLACE(
      'aaa bbb <br> ccc <br> ddd',
      '<br>',
      ''
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL не предназначен для таких задач как преобразование текстов и тем более HTML. Выбирайте правильные средства для решения задач. Но если все таки очень хочется, то конечно можно и на MySQL, но получается жутко:

```
select concat(
        substr(STR,1,length(STR)-length(substring_index(STR, '<br>', -1))-length('<br>')),
        substring_index(STR, '<br>', -1)
       )
  from (
    SELECT 'aaa bbb <br> ccc <br> ddd' as STR
  ) A
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы нашел все br (<br>, <br/>, <br />, < br/>) ?

Comment: @Sergey Заранее все варианты написания replace заменить на один. Или писать какой то дикий case/if который посмотрит позиции каждого из вариантов и выдаст на выходе максимальную позицию. Или патчить  MySQL сервер, добавлять поддержку регулярных выражений https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp

Comment: [Я свой вопрос оформил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569108/mysql-replace-using-regexp),пожалуйста если это вам под силу то помогите

Comment: @Sergey Если это разовая работа, не хотите экспортировать всю таблицу в текстовый файл, там все заменить любым средством работающим с текстом (sed, perl, и т.п.) и залить дамп обратно в БД. Оно быстрее будет. Ну или на любом языке с поддержкой регулярок построчно прочитать и заменить, 1000 записей то немного. А если в БД делать не цепляя вот тот модуль для регулярок - то писать конечный автомат, который посимвольно просмотрит строку

Comment: От меня требуют SQL.То Есть думаю что такие ошибки у них все таки будут повторяться

Comment: @Sergey Ну предположим ... А там точно будет BR или завтра какой нибудь другой тег ? Если тупой конечный автомат - то он будет строго для определенной заменяемой строки. И его переделка под другую строку - переписывание его заново. Реализовывать свой механизм регулярок на SQL ... мягко говоря долго