# Mysql replace using regexp

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения, replace

Существует таблица с 1000 и более записей. В многих из этих записей в тексте в конце какой то мудрец оставил `<br>`.

Коллеги, у меня есть код который меняет последнее вхождение которое передаю в процедуру. На данном примере пытаюсь удалить последний `<br>`.Но загвоздка вот в чем: он меняет по точному совпадению, то есть `<br/>` в пролёте. Как можно организовать так, чтобы он заменил все теги `br` ?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS replaceBr;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE replaceBr (IN mytext TEXT, IN br VARCHAR (255)) 
BEGIN

  SELECT 
    CONCAT(
      SUBSTR(
    mytext,
    1,
    LENGTH(mytext) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mytext, br, - 1)) - LENGTH(br)
      ),
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(mytext, br, - 1 )
    ) ;
END ;
|

DELIMITER ;

CALL replaceBr ('aaa bbb <br> ccc <br > ddd', '<br>') ;
```

Думаю сначала надо привести `mytext` к единому стандарту. То есть заменить все подходящие `br` к единому `<br>`. А потом уже моя функция заработает.

По-моему регулярка выглядит так: `"/[\n\r\s]*<br\s*\/?>[\n\r\s]*/"`.
Но как его применить, как сделать чтобы это все заработало?

Спасибо.

Comment: Есть [вот такая библиотека для поиска и замены на основе регулярных выражений в MySQL](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp), может, подойдёт.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  Нет, к сожалению не подойдет,от меня требуют только SQL

Comment: В тексте могут встречаться посторонние символы `<` и `>` т.е. не являющиеся частью тегов. например `abc <div id="a>x">` (очень натянутый пример конечно) ?

Comment: @Mike Нужны всего лишь `br` ,остальное не интересует

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе можно пробегать по строке в цикле, раз уж вы сделали процедуру, но я привык делать все одним запросом. (Кстати, вашу замену по всей таблице можно выполнить одним запросом без процедур).

Для работы запроса потребуется таблица с порядковыми номерами (она в запросах заменяет цикл, размножая записи). Номера должны быть от 1 до максимальной длины обрабатываемой строки:

```
create table seqnum(X int not null, primary key(X));
insert into seqnum values(1),(2),(3),(4);
insert into seqnum select X+4 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+8 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+16 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+32 from seqnum;
```

А вот пример для замен в одной строке:

```
select coalesce(concat(substr(STR,1,max(X)-1),
              substr(STR,locate('>',STR,max(X))+1)),STR)

  from (
    SELECT 'aaa bbb <br> ccc < br/ > ddd' as STR
  ) A, seqnum S
  where S.X<=length(STR)
    and substr(STR,S.X) REGEXP '^< *br */? *>'
```

Идея в том, что MySQL умеет искать по регулярному выражению, только заменять не умеет. Мы берем нашу строку и последовательно удаляем из нее символы начиная с начала и проверяем оставшийся хвост на соответствие регулярному выражению. Получаем максимальную позицию в строке, в которой регулярка дала положительный результат. Начиная с этой позиции мы и удаляем весь текст до следующего знака `>`. Для обработки целой таблицы строк добавляете в внутренний подзапрос получение строк из той таблицы и в конце добавляете `group by STR` (лучше по уникальному id строк той таблицы).