# Как правильно найти позицию первой русской буквы в строке?

Tags: mysql, sql

Вот такое выражения не работает:

```
instr(`trans`, '[а-я]')
```

Как я понимаю `[а-я]` вот эта часть не верно оформлена.

Comment: @Kromster, главное результат

Comment: Не умеет функция instr искать по диапазону символов. В общем виде стандартными функциями MySQL это не решается. либо создавать собственную функцию, либо эмулировать в запросе цикл и перебирать им символы по одному, примерно как тут  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569108

Comment: Еще можно сделать табличку букв от а до я выполнить join с ней и взять минимальное значение instr от всех букв группируя по строке

Comment: А позицию обязательно через `sql` искать?

Comment: Ну в контексте вопроса да, как найти без его помощи я знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно создать свою функцию и использовать. Один раз выполните запрос:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS PatIndex;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION PatIndex(pattern VARCHAR(255), tblString VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS INTEGER
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INTEGER;
    SET i = 1;
    myloop: WHILE (i <= LENGTH(tblString)) DO
        IF SUBSTRING(tblString, i, 1) REGEXP pattern THEN
            RETURN(i);
            LEAVE myloop;        
        END IF;    
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE; 
    RETURN(0);
END
```

Использование:

```
SELECT fld, PatIndex('[а-я]', fld) As rusIndex
FROM myTable
```